# High CPU usage 130% of a CPU for fail2ban due to epoch datetime retrieval errors

Tags: date, debugging, ssh, epoch, fail2ban

Persistent overseas network attacks being performed on my system without my permission inclined me to install fail2ban since cphulkd does not ban ips. I am monitoring a few services for unwelcome penetration attempts. Once the service was started, I noticed it was using extremely high CPU resources. 22 emails after the startup discloses that the SSH server jail is stopped and started.

Here is my fail2ban.conf
http://pastebin.com/ptCLmpqm

my jail.conf
http://pastebin.com/KDdmTSCL
note my email are obscured for obvious security & spam reasons

fail2ban log
pastebin(dot)com/rq0cqm9J

Comment: Same problem, have you got find solution?

Comment: Could be another log too big and too frequently updated, ie maillog

Comment: I had a similar issue. To debug it I started editing my jail.conf file disabling rules one by one and restarting fail2ban until I found the ones that were causing me problems. As @Veve, my problem was a log file that was getting to big and wasn't being rotated properly.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was running fail2ban only for sshd. My /var/log/auth.log file was huge and configured to rotate only weekly.

I setup daily rotation (and forced the rotation to [run immediately](https://serverfault.com/questions/583442/manually-rotate-a-log-file), which triggered a [permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482773/apache-and-logrotate-configuration)).

This did not fix things until I also

- Stopped fail2ban
- Deleted /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3
- Started fail2ban

With those steps,

```
sudo fail2ban-client status sshd
```

showed bans within a few minutes.